# cached IO for block device

Tags: c, linux, caching

Imagine that I want to use some HDD/SSD as raw block device (without filesystem) for my app.

However, it would be good to perform some RAM caching of readed/written blocks, and one possible approach is to perform application-level caching - but amount of RAM used for cache, obviously, should be explicitly free'd before I can use it for another purposes.

Is there a way to use unused memory for such caching, as it is done for file IO?
Is kernel hacking needed for this?

Comment: Are you saying there's no OS caching for raw block devices?

Comment: Do you realise that you are effectively attempting to implement a file system in a user process?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't know if OS performs caching for raw devices, and that's the reason why I'm asking :)

Comment: @wildplasser: That's not necesary true... he didn't mention files, directories, locking and all other stuff.. could be just one single binary "file".

Comment: @John Rivers: A simple performance test could quickly verify this.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: He does not have to use any of the dir/file/locking stuff. Just using a (fixed sized) file on an existing filesytem , maybe mmap()ing it, would give him all the LRU buffering, etc he needs almost for free. Plus: the "spare" memory will be used as FS-buffers.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath of course I can make performance test to make sure it is cached; however, it would be great to know some theory about how it works (not just empirical results).

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm perfectly aware of that. But that != "effectively attempting to implement a file system"